# C# list<string, list<string>> how to?

Tags: c#

I've spent some time on the internet trying to find a solution, but my skills in C# are at a beginner level and I did not find any ways to do what i wanted to.

So here is the situation :

I have a web service that return an object to me, in this object there is a two dimensional table. What I'd like to do is running along this table and put these value inside a `List`. To illustrate that here is an example and what I already have :

```
// creation of a list like : List <String, List<String>> myList
for (int i = 0; i < outPut.errors.Length; i++)
{
    string error = outPut.errors[i].data.label;
    //myList.add(error);
    if (outPut.errors[i].data.label != "" && outPut.errors[i] != null)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < outPut.errors[i].data.corrections.Length; j++)
         {
              string corrections  = outPut.errors[j].data.corrections[0][j].ToString();
              //myList.add(corrections)
         }  
    }
}
```

So in this example i create a two dimension List where the first argument is a String and the second is a List (just like a two dimensional table would have tab[x][y] where there is multiple Y for one X.

Apparently in C# you have to know the exact size to create a two dimensional table, and we will never know what will be the size of this table.

So is it possible to create a list such as i'd like to do it or should i do it another way?

Comment: You mean `List<List<string>>`? `List` only has 1 generic parameter.

Comment: A list can not be two-dimensional, it is not an array. Just create an encapsulating class that has the properties *string* and *list<string>* and then populate your outer List with objects of that type. Update: You can use a *Dictionary<string, List<string>>*, of course, but iterating over it is a bit more work.

Comment: Are you looking for `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` or could you actually create a `DataTable`?

Comment: @Kroltan: *List<List<string>>* is totally valid, btw.

Comment: @Kroltan, i have already see List<List<string>> but the problème is in this list each element is a list, for me i need to that the first element of a line is a String and the seconde element in the line is a List.

Comment: @Robert i tryed by creating an object but the fact is i need ti to stay string and not become an object because i will send it after to Javascript for manipulation.

Comment: @Robert I know, but the OP was asking for some sort of `List<string, List<string>`. @Slayner: You can use a Tuple, or use a Dictionary instead of the first level of the list. For tables with headings but not necessarily a colum order, a dictionary is ideal (`Dictionary<string, List<string>>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a 2 dimensional list use `List<List<string>>` to define a list where each entry is a list containing strings. You will need to create each "row" list as you come to it, they will not be automatically created for you.

However that is not really what you want in this case as you have the special label field. In this case you should create an object with your string label and list inside it and then have a list of that. Or alternatively if you expect to be looking things up by their label and will not have duplicate labels you could consider a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: yeah i already try List<List<string>> but i need to keep the fact that labal is a single string related to a List<string> like you said after. there will be no duplicate in the table i got because i will remove all duplicate before addign them to myList. I will look for the Dictionary thing, if you have an exemple i will gladly take it to see what it does exactly.

Comment: Plenty of examples online, a quick google found this for example: http://www.learncs.org/en/Dictionaries

Comment: Note that the dictionary will handle detecting duplicates for you very easily.

Comment: Okay for what i have find already on Dictionaries, it's seems to be the stuff i need, i just have one question about it, is it possible to return the dictionaries at the end? ( because after this i will have to send it back to my Javascript so i can work on this).

Comment: Returning them: Yes. Passing them back to Javascript: I'd have thought so. It's not something I've done (I don't use C# much) but I'm sure it's possible, If you have problems doing that ask it as a separate question though and how you do it would depend on what framework you are using etc.

Comment: Okay, well thanks a lot, i'm going to work around this and find my way, if i don't manage to succes in a few day for the javascritp part i'll post another question but for now is time to work on my onw.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the use of a Tuple as follows:

```
List<Tuple<String, List<String>>>
```

Have a look at the details of Tuple here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx
Basically it is a class for storing tuples, pretty much what you are after.
The first item is a String, and the second is a List

Comment: Or if the columns don't need to be ordered, a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: the column don't need to be ordered, if i get this right with tuple i can have something like Tuple <string, string[]> = ...
And having a table for seconde argument without giving him the size of this table ?